# How to implement resource_filename in pkg_resources?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, pkg-resources

I wrote a package that imports `pkg_resource` package provided by [distribute 0.6.35](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute). I import `pkg_resource` because I need its `resource_filename` to get the path of a built-in data. However, the `pkg_resource` is not built-in in python3 and need to install. About this, I have two questions:

1. Why Python3 doesn't provide `pkg_resource` in its official distribution? Does that mean `pkg_resource` is deprecated or `Python3` has an alternative package for `pkg_resource` built-in?
2. If Python3 doesn't have alternative package for `pkg_resource`, how can I write my own version of `resource_filename` with built-in libraries? Is it easy to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `pkg_resource` is not a part of neither Python 2, nor Python 3 official distributions. It's part of `distribute`

Comment: @DJV I agree with you.. I was just wondering that why neither of them provide `distribute` as built-in package.. It's so useful.

Comment: Don't know actually, I guess for the same reason `setuptools` is not a part of the standard distribution as well.

Answer (score 1):

`distribute` is merged back to `setuptools`. [`setuptools`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/overview) supports Python 3.